# How to use ,var-name (defvar) syntax in org-publish-project-alist? Init file is in form of org-mode

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-babel, string, backquote

I have following function as part of my emacs configuration.org settings for publishing org to html.

```
(defvar website-html-preamble
"<nav>
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
   <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
   <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
   <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
 </ul>
 </nav>")

 (defvar website-html-postamble 
     "<div class='footer'> Copyright 2016 %a (%v HTML).<br>Last updated %C. <br>   </div>")

  (setq org-publish-project-alist
    '(
      ("website" :components ("orgfiles"))
      ("orgfiles"
       :base-directory  ,org-mode-websrc-directory
       :base-extension "org"
       :publishing-directory  ,org-mode-publishing-directory
       :exclude "*/excluded/*" 
       :recursive t
       :publishing-function org-twbs-publish-to-html
       :headline-levels 3
   :section-numbers nil
       :with-toc nil
   :html-preamble ,website-html-preamble
   :Html-postamble ,website-html-postamble
      )
      )
)
```

",var-name"  (eg: ,website-html-preamble) causes following problems (using org-babel-load-file to load config)

> Debugger entered--Lisp error: (invalid-read-syntax "#")
>   eval-buffer(# nil "c:/rahuketu/programming/EMAC/Emacs_Config/.emacs.d/configuration.el"
>   nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 4284
>   load-with-code-conversion("c:/rahuketu/programming/EMACS/Emacs_Config/.emacs.d/configuration.el"
>   "c:/rahuketu/programming/EMACS/Emacs_Config/.emacs.d/configuration.el"
>   nil nil)
>   load("c:/rahuketu/programming/EMACS/Emacs_Config/.emacs.d/configuration.el"
>   nil nil t)
>   load-file("c:/rahuketu/programming/EMACS/Emacs_Config/.emacs.d/configuration.el")
>   org-babel-load-file("c:/rahuketu/programming/EMACS/Emacs_Config/.emacs.d/configuration.org")
>   eval-buffer(# nil
>   "c:/rahuketu/programming/EMACS/Emacs_Config/.emacs.d/init.el" nil t) 
>   ; Reading at buffer position 422
>   load-with-code-conversion("c:/rahuketu/programming/EMACS/Emacs_Config/.emacs.d/init.el"
>   "c:/rahuketu/programming/EMACS/Emacs_Config/.emacs.d/init.el" t t)
>     load("c:/rahuketu/programming/EMACS/Emacs_Config/.emacs.d/init" t t)
>
> ## [0 "\205\262 \306=\203  command-line()   normal-top-level()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a back quote if you want the variables with commas to be replaced. See [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html).

But that's not where the error is coming from. You don't appear to have escaped the quote characters inside your preamble string. [Reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-for-Strings.html)

Comment: Thanks I have modified code to fix for quote inside the preamble string. However `backquote bit was the tricky one. Thanks for your help